# Mysterious Perl Syntax Errors?

Tags: perl

My Perl code is throwing me two syntax errors on the commented lines, but I cannot parse what's wrong here (I've put it through a couple of tools). I'm admittedly very new to Perl but I don't know what's wrong as the compiler is very unspecific.

```
while (<$file>)
 {  
#if(/(udp(\d*):\/\/)([^\s,]+|\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+)(\sFace\sId:....\))?/)
    {
        $resolvable = $2;
        $output = $1.$2
        if(!exists $testedhash{"$resolvable"}){
            $testedhash{"$resolvable"} = 1;
            if($resolvable =~ /(\d+)\.(\d+)\.(\d+)\.(\d+)/)
            {
                my $temp = 255;
                if($1 gt $temp || $2 gt $temp || $3 gt $temp || $4 gt $temp)
                {
                    print "$_ is malformed\n"
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if($n->ping($resolvable))
                {
                    print "$output is up\n"
                }
                else
                {
                    print "$resolvable is down\n"
                }
            }
        }
    #}
 }
```

Comment: Missing semicolon after `$output = $1.$2` makes the following `if` into a statement modifier, and eventually the parser realizes it can't make that work.

Comment: You also need to remove the comment mark from  the `#}` in the second to last line so that all braces are balanced.

Comment: You probably want to `use strict;` and `use warnings;` at the beginning of your code.

Comment: `gt` is the stringwise comparison operator. You want `>` if you’re comparing numbers.

Comment: there're more `{` than `}` I think you should comment the one directly under your commented `if`  you should also be consistent in the place you write `{` after a control structure/loop. Either on the same line, or on the next line, but you should be consistent ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rule of thumb when trying to trace syntax errors, is look at the line before.

Your error points to:

```
        if(!exists $testedhash{"$resolvable"}){
```

But actually, that's the 'end' of the error - the point at which perl is sure that there's a problem.

It starts with the whole statement that's a part of. And because you're missing a `;` on the preceeding line, that's "counted".

Your statement is actually:

```
    $output = $1.$2 if(!exists $testedhash{"$resolvable"}){
```

And up until that `{` that's valid - you can assign a value based on a post condition.

However, you really want to include in your code:

- `use strict;`
- `use warnings;`
- and if you're not sure about an error - `use diagnostics;`

You've a few other logic errors in your code which have been noted in the comments - your `$1` and `$2` aren't valid when you've commented out your regex. And also `gt` is probably not the thing you want - it's a string comparison - so "10" comes before "2" instead of after like you might be expecting.

Comment: This was a section of code that I was having errors in, I removed the boilerplate for conciseness' sake. However, this did fix my error- I'm generally used to languages with more verbose errors, so thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

SO doesn't really reward this, blah blah blah, whine, whatever.  But I tidied up your code and threw some comments in on what I changed.  I hope you find it helpful.

Note that I didn't actually test this, so I could have busted it all up.  YMMV, known to cause cancer in laboratory rats, 3 out of 4 dentists like to chew gum.

```
use strict;    # Until you understand why you wouldn't want it, use strict.  It will save you a ton of errors.
use warnings;  # Same with warnings.

# Break up your regexes into labeled pieces
# It makes them easier to understand.
my $UDP_DATA = qr{udp\d*://};
my $HOST_NAME = qr/[^\s,]+/;
my $HOST_IP4_ADDRESS = qr/\d+\(?.\d+){3}/;
my $SOME_STUFF = qr/Face\sId:..../;


my $n = SomeKindOfPinger->new();

while (defined my $line = <$file>) {

    # Use early returns and loop continuation to avoid deep nesting.
    # Extended regexes let you use space and comments in regexes to make them even easier to read.
    next unless $line =~ m{
            ( $UDP_DATA )
            (   $HOST_IP4_ADDRESS
              | $HOST_NAME
            )
            \s $SOME_STUFF
        }x;

    # Use better variable names, output could be anything.
    # we don't know if resolvable is resolvable at this point, so it's just a host.
    my $label = "$1$2";
    my $host = $2;

    # Bail out avoids nesting again.
    # Variable names with types in them like "some_hash" or "monkey_array" are a code smell.
    next if exists $tested_hosts{$host};

    $tested_hosts{$host}++;

    # We got to reuse that regex piece. Handy.
    if ( $host =~ $HOST_IP4_ADDRESS ) {
        # If you have a bunch of checks to do, put them in a data structure and iterate
        my @octets = split /\./, $host;
        my @bad = grep $_>255, @octets; # grep is like JS 'filter' function.
                                        # This says: "Show me the malformed octets."

        # An array, like @bad, in scalar context to the number of items in the array.
        # So it returns 0 or FALSE if it is empty.
        # So if any octets are malformed, we print the message.
        print "$line is malformed\n"
            if @bad;
    }
    else {
        # if you are doing the same kind of operation, no matter how an if/else chain goes,
        # just with different data, use a ternary operator.
        # Here, we print no matter what.
        # So if ping is true, we print the happy message. Otherwise we print the sad message.
        print $n->ping($host)
            ? "$label is up\n"
            : "$label is busted\n";
    }
}
```